# How to specialize a type parameterized argument to multiple different types for in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, types

I need a back-check (please).

In an article ( http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2010/06/automatic-differentiation-with-scala/ ) I just wrote I stated that it is my belief in Scala that you can not specify a function that takes an argument that is itself a function with an unbound type parameter.  I have edited this question to try and simplify the example.

The following code works by introducing a trait GenericFn that imitates the Scala Function1 trait, except it has a free-type parameter in the function:

```
object TypeExample {
    trait NumberBase {
        def result:String
    }

    class A extends NumberBase {
        def result = "A"
    }

    class B extends NumberBase {
        def result = "B"
    }

    trait GenericFn {
        def apply[X<:NumberBase](x:X):String
    }

    def specializeAndApplyTwice(f:GenericFn):String = {
        f[A](new A()) + f[B](new B())
    }

    def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
        val f = new GenericFn {
            def apply[X<:NumberBase](x:X):String = { x.result }
        }
        println(specializeAndApplyTwice(f))
    }
}
```

This works, but is there a way to do this without the GenericFn trait (use a standard function notation)?  For example the code below fails with the compile-time error: "type mismatch;  found   : TypeExample2.A  required: _$1 where type _$1 <: TypeExample2.NumberBase":

```
def specializeAndApplyTwice(f:(_<:NumberBase)=>String):String = {
   f(new A()) + f(new B())
}
```

Comment: Your example should probably be: def g(f:Array[Double]=>Double, x:Array[Double]):Double

Comment: ...and perhaps, the second exampe should be def g(f[Y]:Array[Y]=>Y, x: Array[Y]): Y? Otherwise you could write def g(f:Array[_] => Double, x: Array[Double]):Double, but I assume that this is not what you want.

Comment: Arjan, actually my examples are closer to what I want.  In my actual code Y has a type constraint (which I didn't reproduce here) of the form Y<:NumberBase[Y] and NumberBase[Y] declares methods for converting to and from Y's and Doubles. g() uses this structure to up-convert from machine Doubles into Ys, do some work and then down-convert to Doubles (so the outside code doesn't pick Y's type and doesn't need to deal with Y's type).

Comment: I have replaced the question with a new (simpler) example that gets rid of some non-essential details (arrays, parameterization of types).  The question is now how to eliminate the GenericFn trait in favor of some function notation.

Answer (score 2):

Restating the initial motivation for the question: We want to give a type to a *value* 'g' because we want to pass it around. Scala values (of course) cannot have polymorphic type, even if they are function values. So how to give a type where some part of it is unknown?

So I believe one solution is to use wildcards (a form of existential abstraction):

```
  def g(f: Array[_ <: NumberBase[_]] => Double, z: Array[Double]): Double
```

The prose explanation for the type of g is: a function from Array[T] and Array[Double] to Double, where T is *some* type that extends Double. "some" is the word that indicates existential abstraction, we ask that such a type exists although we do not care at this point which one it is.

Comment: I heavily edited the question to try and slot your example in.  I couldn't get it to work- but obviously that may be my fault (I don't know much about the various _ notations).

Comment: In the reformulated question, it seems simpler to use
<code>def specializeAndApplyTwice(f:NumberBase=>String)</code>...

I believe there is added difficulty in the original formulation because one needed to use the type parameter (or the wildcard type _) to build an Array type. 

BTW for completeness: functions from types to values are well known in theory (the calculus is called F-omega) but Scala does not have them in their pure form. Would need an suitable VM.

_ in types always means a wildcard type. Maybe you find this page useful, it has some examples http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43